# PHP switch statement - echo error

Tags: php, switch-statement

Firstly, this is not the best way to write the overall code but I am trying to practice switch statements so I am using the same form and error messages to practice different php functions and statements etc

In this particular case, the case number (case 1, case 2, case 3 etc) is being included in my echo statement and I am not sure why

So in the example given, in the form under username I enter the letter C and expect the error to simply output as "Username must be a minimum of 6 characters" but what is is actually coming out as is "Username must be a minimum of 6 characters2"

I have tried putting the number value for the initial variable setting at the start by the various if statements into "" and the same when i get to the case switch statements in case it had to read as text but this didn't make any difference

Any help on this would be appreciated. Likely something very simple. p.s please don't laugh at my code....too much

`

```
<?php 
##### Form Handling ####
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

### Error Handling ###

// define variables and set to empty values
$userErr = $firstnameErr = $surnameErr = $emailErr = "";
$user = $firstname = $surname = $email = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
  if (empty($_POST["user"])) 
  {
    $userErr = 1;
  } 
  else 
  {
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    if (strlen($user) < 6) {
        $userErr = 2;
    } 
    if(strlen(trim($username)) != strlen($username)) {
        $userErr = 3;
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
       {$firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
    $surnameErr = "Surname is required";
  } else {
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname))
       {$surnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; }
  }
} 
?>

<form action="form_register.php" method="POST">
<p>Username:
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $user;?>"> 
<?php 
switch($userErr) 
    {
    case 1:
        echo "Username is required";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Username must be a minimum of 6 characters";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Must not contain any spaces";
        break;
    default:
        echo "*";
        break;
    }
echo $userErr;?> </p>



<p>First Name:
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if ( isset ($_POST['firstname']))
    echo $_POST['firstname'] ; ?>"> </p>
<p>Surname:
<input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php if ( isset ($_POST['surname']))
    echo $_POST['surname'] ; ?>"> </p>
<p>Email Address:
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if ( isset ($_POST['email']))
    echo $_POST['email'] ; ?>"> </p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly after the case block, you're echoing the number itself:

```
echo $userErr;?>
```

Remove that `echo` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I needed the echo statement to output the error statement. That has indeed corrected it